# Degree formula for smash product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f : S^n \to S^n$ and $g : S^m \to S^m$ be two maps with degrees $d_f$ and $d_g$ respectively. These two map gives rise to a map $f \wedge g : S^{n+m} \to S^{n+m}$.

My question is how the degree of the map $f \wedge g$ is related to $d_f$ and $d_g?$

Comment: The degree of $f \wedge g$ is $d_f \cdot d_g$ assuming they are basepoint-preserving.

Comment: @AlvinJin: Thank you so much. Please explain how do you get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The degree of $f \wedge g$ is $d_f \cdot d_g$.  To see this, recall that $\deg (f \circ g) = \deg f \cdot \deg g$.

Now, to use this, note that $f \wedge g$ is the composition of $f \wedge 1$ and $1 \wedge g$.  If we show $\deg (f \wedge 1) = \deg f$ and $\deg (1 \wedge g) = \deg g$ then we will be done.

To do this, we use suspensions.  We'll first show that $\deg (f \wedge 1) = \deg f$.  Note that the quotient map $S(S^n) \to S^n \wedge S^1$ induces an isomorphism on homology since it collapses a contractible subcomplex to a point so we get a commutative diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S(S^n) @>{Sf}>> S(S^n)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
S^n \wedge S^1 @>{f \wedge 1}>> S^n \wedge S^1
\end{CD}
$$

From this, there is an induced commutative diagram of homology groups $H_{n+1}$, which implies that $\deg f = \deg Sf = \deg f \wedge 1$ (where the first equality follows since suspensions preserve degree).  The result for $g$ follows similarly.